Azure DevOps pipeline unable to clean the working directory at the start/end of pipeline run
I am using azure DevOps self hosted runners to do some tests
pipeline file:
    name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
    
    trigger: none
    
    pr:
    - master
    - main
    - release*
    
    pool:
      name: sonarcube-agents
    
    variables:
      AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION: testsub-dev
      IMAGE_NAME: $(Build.DefinitionName)
      SOURCE_DIRECTORY: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
     
    
    #specifying resources #test change to trigger 15
    jobs:
    - job: BuildAndTest
      displayName: 'Build and Test Job'
      steps:
      - script: |
          echo "Running on self-hosted agent"
          echo "Step 1: Checking out the repository"
        displayName: 'Checkout Code'
        
      - checkout: self
        #clean: true
      
      
      # more steps here that run the tests and generate some files
      # in the working directory. we run some docker containers and 
      # run unit tests. at end of pipeline we are left with new 
      # files which are reports of qa tests. I do stop all
      # containers and delete all images and volumes as you can see.
      # make test cmd triggers a Makefile which does most of the work. 
      # (start all containers, run tests, and generate the test reports etc)

    - script: |
          echo "lets run tests"
          make test
          echo "end of tests #"
          echo "*********"
          echo "**********"
          echo "lets clean up \n lets stop containers"
          docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
          echo "lets clean up \n lets remove all images and containers"
          yes | docker system prune -a
          echo "check if anything still - docker ps -a"
          docker ps -a
          echo "check all volumes: "
          docker volume ls -qf dangling=true
          echo "remove all docker volumes"
          docker volume remove $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
        displayName: runtestswithmakefile
    
      
      # here I am trying to remove all the extra files but it does not help.
      - script: |
          shopt -s dotglob
          rm -rf *

      workspace: # Workspace options on the agent.
        clean: all

theoretically the part:
      workspace: # Workspace options on the agent.
        clean: all

should clean up all the working directory before starting the new pipeline but I am getting errors when we trigger new pipeline that working directory is not empty:

##[error]One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Access to the path '/data/vsts-agent/workspace/1/s/pycache/app.cpython-39.pyc' is denied.)) (One or more errors occurred. (Access to the path '/data/vsts-agent/workspace/1/s/migrations/pycache/env.cpython-39.pyc' is denied.)) (Access to the path '/data/vsts-agent/workspace/1/s/pycache/app.cpython-39.pyc' is denied.) (Access to the path '/data/vsts-agent/workspace/1/s/migrations/pycache/env.cpython-39.pyc' is denied.)

this is the actual working directory of the pipeline:
/data/vsts-agent/workspace/1/s/

and
__pycache__/

is one of the folders created by previous pipeline when tests were running.
If I ssh into the runner and clean up the working directory, pipeline runs fine for 1st time. Fails again on second run because of output directories and files produced by previous successful run.

You can try to add a script task to delete the files in the $(Build.SourcesDirectory) (your /data/vsts-agent/workspace/1/s folder) before checkout the repo.
jobs:
- job: BuildAndTest
  displayName: 'Build and Test Job'
  workspace: 
    clean: all
  steps:       
  - script: |
        tree   $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    displayName: Show files in $(Build.SourcesDirectory) 
  - script: |
        rm -r $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/*
    displayName: delete files in  $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    continueOnError: true
  - script: |
        tree   $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    displayName: Show files in $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
  - checkout: self

If the delete command doesn't work, these pycache files may locked because they might still be in use by a Python process, which could prevent them from being deleted.
In this case, we can add script task to kill the Python process first.
jobs:
- job: BuildAndTest
  displayName: 'Build and Test Job'
  workspace: 
    clean: all
  steps:       
  - script: |
        tree   $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    displayName: Show files in $(Build.SourcesDirectory) 
  - script: |
        ps aux | grep python
        pkill -f python
    displayName: kill python process that may use the files
    continueOnError: true
  - script: |
        rm -r $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/*
    displayName: delete files in  $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    continueOnError: true

  - script: |
        tree   $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    displayName: Show files in $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

  - checkout: self

If the files cannot be deleted and they are not in use by any Python process, you can check if the agent account that the self-hosted agent run against has the correct permission to delete files.
If the permission is not enough, you can reconfigure the self-hosted agent to run with an agent account with correct permission, such as the admin account.
By the way, the workspace clean is used to decide what to clean up before the job runs. It should be used in the job definition. Placing it at the end of the job may lead to confusion.
- job: myJob
  workspace:
    clean: outputs | resources | all # what to clean up before the job runs

